# Migrate from Pushwoosh to FCM

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

Is there a way to migrate our registered devices from Pushwoosh to Firebase Cloud Messaging?  We are switching push notification services but I dont want to lose the existing registered device.